# Use NGINX as file server, and decompress .gz, .zip, .7z, and.tar files inside of it

Tags: bash, docker, nginx, docker-compose, compression

I'm trying to use NGINX as file server, and trying to click on some files inside this server, typically commpressed in **.gz, .zip, .7z**, and **.tar** formats.

But I have only be able to uncompress **.gz** with the  configuration of the following files, it seems that my bash script isn't running, anyone knows why?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y zip

RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY scripts/decompress.sh /usr/share/nginx/html/
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/decompress.sh

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
```

This is my `nginx.conf` file:

````
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css
               application/json
               application/javascript
               text/xml
               application/xml
               application/xml+rss
               text/javascript;
    
    server {
        listen 7756;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location /files {
            # alias /usr/share/nginx/files;
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size on;
            autoindex_localtime on; 
        }

        # TODO: MAYBE THIS IS THE RIGHT THING TO DO.
        location ~ ^/files/(.*\.(gz|zip))$ {
            # alias /usr/share/nginx/html/$1.gz;
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/$1;
            add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$1"';
            types { application/octet-stream .gz .zip; }
            gzip off;
            try_files $uri @execute_script;
        }

        location @execute_script {
            internal;
            rewrite ^ /usr/share/nginx/html/decompress.sh last;
        }

    }
}```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```.yaml
version: '3.9'

networks:
  nginx-file-server-network:
    name: nginx-file-server-network
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx-file-server-service:
    container_name: nginx-file-server-service

    image: nginx-file-server-image:1.0

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    
    volumes:
      # - ./files:/usr/share/nginx/files
      - ./files:/usr/share/nginx/html

    ports:
      - 7756:7756
    
    networks:
      - nginx-file-server-network
````

And finally, this is my decompression script, which is intended to have more conditions, each one based on the different files ben uncompressed.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" =~ .*\.gz$ ]]; then
    echo "Decompressing the .gz file: $1" 
    gzip -d "$1"
elif [[ "$1" =~  .*\.zip$ ]]; then
    echo "Extracting .zip file: $1"
    unzip "$1"
else
fi
```